# Apache Storm & Vagrant. org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache, vagrant, apache-storm

I'm new to Apache Storm and Vagrant and I want to deploy my topology on virtualized cluster built using Vagrant. However I'm constantly getting `org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException` from Storm UI:

```
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts ["nimbus"]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:90)
at org.apache.storm.ui.core$all_topologies_summary.invoke(core.clj:434)
at org.apache.storm.ui.core$fn__12605.invoke(core.clj:952)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$make_route$fn__4631.invoke(core.clj:100)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$if_route$fn__4619.invoke(core.clj:46)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$if_method$fn__4612.invoke(core.clj:31)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routing$fn__4637.invoke(core.clj:113)
at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2570)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:113)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routes$fn__4641.invoke(core.clj:118)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.json$wrap_json_params$fn__12065.invoke(json.clj:56)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__5766.invoke(multipart_params.clj:118)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__11217.invoke(reload.clj:22)
at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers$requests_middleware$fn__6019.invoke(helpers.clj:50)
at org.apache.storm.ui.core$catch_errors$fn__12786.invoke(core.clj:1225)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__5686.invoke(keyword_params.clj:35)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__5729.invoke(nested_params.clj:84)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__5658.invoke(params.clj:64)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__5766.invoke(multipart_params.clj:118)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.flash$wrap_flash$fn__5981.invoke(flash.clj:35)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.session$wrap_session$fn__5967.invoke(session.clj:98)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet$make_service_method$fn__5516.invoke(servlet.clj:127)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet$servlet$fn__5520.invoke(servlet.clj:136)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet.proxy$javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$ff19274a.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:654)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
at org.apache.storm.logging.filters.AccessLoggingFilter.handle(AccessLoggingFilter.java:47)
at org.apache.storm.logging.filters.AccessLoggingFilter.doFilter(AccessLoggingFilter.java:39)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers$x_frame_options_filter_handler$fn__6112.invoke(helpers.clj:189)
at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers.proxy$java.lang.Object$Filter$abec9a8f.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:247)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:210)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:369)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:933)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:995)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the tail of `nimbus.log` file on nimbus machine:

```
2017-02-10 11:35:12.768 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/192.168.50.3:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-02-10 11:35:12.769 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [WARN] Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Here is repo with my configuration: https://github.com/alxg2112/storm-vagrant-cluster.

Please advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found the solution. Here's what I did:

1) On zookeeper VM run `sudo nano /etc/environment` and changed contents to following:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386"
ZOOKEEPER_HOME="/usr/share/zookeeper-3.4.9"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin"
```

2) Run `source /etc/environment`

3) Restarted zookeeper by running `sudo /usr/share/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh restart`

That's it! After following steps cluster was up and running.
Basically, all I needed to do is to add `JAVA_HOME` and `ZOOKEEPER_HOME` variables and update `PATH`.
Hope someone will find this helpful!